# google v2 ct list deprecated

Tags: android, certificate-pinning

I have implemented Certificate transparency using com.appmattus.certificatetransparency:certificatetransparency library. Now v2 list is not supported by google and every API is giving this error

```
Failure: Unable to load log servers with log-list.json failed to load with java.io.IOException: Invalid response 404
at com.appmattus.certificatetransparency.internal.loglist.CallExtKt$await$2$1$1.onResponse(CallExt.kt:45)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:519)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
```

How can I solve this?